# rating Bar não fica com números certos (inteiro) de estrelas

Tags: android

Olá, estou utilizando uma rating bar no android studio e utilizei o seguinte no layout:

```
<RatingBar
   android:id="@+id/ratingBar"
   style="?android:attr/ratingBarStyleSmall"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
   android:background="#ffffff"
   android:isIndicator="false"
   android:numStars="5"
   android:padding="5dp"
   android:stepSize="1"
   android:layout_width="wrap_content" />
```

Acontece que de jeito nenhum ela fica com 5 estrelas, ela mostra 4 e um pouquinho da 5.
Alguém sabe como corrigir isto?
Obrigada.

Comment: olá @Elaine Breda Schwaner, tenta setar `android:layout_width="match_parent"` ao invés de `android:layout_width="wrap_content"`

Comment: Obrigada pela resposta, mas já tentei isto. O que acontece com o match é que a aí aparece muito mais que 5 estrelinhas.

Comment: nunca usei isso nos meus apps, mas vou fazer uns testes aqui, se voce conseguir avisa

Comment: pronto, testei lá, eu coloquei `android:numStars="6"` e apareceram as 5 normalmente. Valeus por ter me dado essa dica, nunca tinha me atinado para esse componente, ririri

Comment: No meu, não deu certo... Se coloco 6 aparece 5 e um pouquinho da 6

Comment: tenta entaum por `android:layout_width="90dp"`por exemplo e vai diminuindo ou aumentando o valor de widith até sumir a que fica pela metade, aqui no meu fica normal independente do numero de stars que uso

Comment: Não deu. Pq daí ele varia o número de estrelas conforme o tamanho do celular do usuário

Answer (score 1, accepted):

opa, entaum confirma ai se é isso que voce precisa

```
<RatingBar
    android:id="@+id/ratingBar"
    style="?android:attr/ratingBarStyleSmall"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:background="#ffffff"
    android:isIndicator="false"
    android:numStars="5"
    android:padding="0dp"
    android:stepSize="1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content">
</RatingBar>
```

note que ao ivés de usar **padding="5dp"** eu usei **padding="0dp"** dai funcionou redondinho, veja nas telas:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Oi! Sim. Era isso. Agora funcionou perfeitamente!!

Comment: Obrigada! Armando. Não imaginei que o padding influenciaria